# Unable to access GeoJSON properties with ":" using JS variable

Tags: javascript, mapbox, openstreetmap, geojson

I am currently following [the tutorial on Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/building-a-store-locator/#initialize-the-map) to build a store locator with a map.

I'm having problems displaying data from my GeoJSON file that I got from Turbo Overpass. Example of the GeoJSON being used :

```json
"properties": {
    "@id": "node/5750820619",
    "addr:city": "Caissargues",
    "addr:housenumber": "180",
    "addr:postcode": "30132",
    "addr:street": "Avenue de la Vistrenque",
    "description:covid19": "horaires légèrement réduits",
    "name": "Bio Marché",
},
```

In my Javascript file I can access properties such as name using this code :

```js
var details = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
details.innerHTML = prop.addr:city;
```

...but am unable to figure out how to access the `addr:city` or `addr:postcode` field as I either get an unexpected identified in vs code or it returns a undefined value in the website. I've tried using `prop.addr:city;`, `prop.addr/':city'/;` and other ways proposed on websites.

If someone could point me in the right direction or propose the solution I would be very grateful.
Thanks !

Comment: According to your  JSON, isn't the data returned as `properties`, not `prop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access these properties like this:

```
details.innerHTML = prop['addr:city'];
```

This works because in Javascript object properties can always be accessed using these brackets.

For example this:

```
const a = prop.a;
```

is equal to

```
const a = prop['a'];
```

However using the last syntax Javascript is a lot more relaxed. You could even do this:

```
const property = prop['some property with lots of spaces'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mathyn, this has fixed my problem and appreciate the explanation on why it works that way.